# How would i get this text alone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, spyder

I'm trying to webscrape https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/uk-top-40-singles-chart/ and get all the titles.
This is my code so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/uk-top-40-singles-chart/'

#opening coonnection, grabbing page
uClient = uReq (my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
#print (page_soup.p)

#grabs each section
containers = page_soup.findAll('div' ,{"class":"title-artist"})

contain = containers[0]
container = containers[0]
```

But I am currently at a stage where I need to get a title by its self. So far I've tried: container.div.a which has narrowed the html to:

```
<a href="/search/singles/savage-love-(laxed---siren-beat)/">SAVAGE LOVE (LAXED - SIREN BEAT)</a>
```

I need to get the title "SAVAGE LOVE (LAXED - SIREN BEAT)" by itself but I am unsure on how to do that.
I am using Spyder and Python 3.7
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.text` attribute should give you what you want.

Solution:

```
>>> container.find('a').text
'SAVAGE LOVE (LAXED - SIREN BEAT)'
```

Comment: and the corresponding function is `.get_text()` (for the sake of completion)

Comment: Thank you guys so much! Really appreciate it :))